# update android studio some conflicts gradle problems absent

Tags: android

I have a problem updating Android studio 1.4 to 1.4.1:

[image]

Comment: @tinysunlight for me, when updating to 1.5, conflicts on **plugins/android/lib/templates** appeared. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: just uninstall now version,and install a new  one.

Answer (score 2):

solved. I followed these steps:
1.- download gradle 2.4  http://gradle.org/gradle-download/
2.- copy gradle.incs to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\media
3.- update android studio
4.- ready, enjoy android studio